# Cannot Select Checkbox List Tile Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, checkboxlist

I've created a map of values to make checkboxes. The map consists of String and bools and when the value of the bool is changed, the check box value should change.

EDIT 1:

My ListView Checkbox

```
CheckboxListTile(
                    title: new Text(
                      key,
                      style: textHeaderStyle,
                    ),
                    value: _selectedOrders.contains(undeliveryOrders[key]),
                    activeColor: Colors.pink,
                    checkColor: Colors.white,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      setState(() {

                        if(value){
                        _selectedOrders.add(undeliveryOrders[key]);
                        undeliveryOrders[key] = value;

                        }else{
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedOrders.remove(undeliveryOrders[key]);
                          });
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  )
```

Creating the Map:

```
        void _formatOrders(availableOrders) {
    for (int i = 0; i < availableOrders.length; i++) {
      var tempOrder = '${availableOrders[i].customer.uniqueInfo.name} , ${availableOrders[i].address}';
      undeliveryOrders['$tempOrder'] = false;

    }
          print('$undeliveryOrders');
          print('$numbers');

  }
```

Selected Order Method

```
var _selectedOrders = [];

  getItems() {
    undeliveryOrders.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == false) {
        _selectedOrders.add(key);
      }
    });

    print(_selectedOrders);

    _selectedOrders.clear();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the `setState()` is not responding, try to use `StatefulBuilder()`.

For Example:

```dart
...

bool isSelected = false;

StatefulBuilder(
  builder: (context, _setState) {
     return ListView(
          children: [
          CheckboxListTile(
              value: isSelected, 
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  _setState(() => isSelected = value);
              },
         ),
       ],
     );
  },
);
...
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you might be over complicating things every value does not have to be mapped to a boolean the way I do it is I add the value that gets checked to an array then check if that item is in that array if it is its true if not its false. You just have to remember to remove the item if the checkbox is unchecked here is some sample code for you.

```
List<String> items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
List<String> isChecked = [];
//Initialized outside build

ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...items
                .map(
                  (item) => CheckboxListTile(
                    subtitle: Text('This is a subtitle'),
                    secondary: Text('This is Secondary text'),
                    title: Text(item),
                    value: isChecked.contains(item),
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      if (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          isChecked.add(item);
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          isChecked.remove(item);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                )
                .toList()
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I only have one problem. When I select any checkbox, all items are selected. I may have misrepresented things as I have to map the values in as the data is dynamically generated. I'll show what I have edited now.

Comment: Never Mind. I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code bellow ?

```
               onChanged: (bool value) {
                  setState(() {
                    undeliveryOrders[key] = value ?? false;
                  });
                },
```